# Why can't I use "group by" instead of a "where"clause? #Mysql #sql

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, where-clause

**Mysql doesn't execute the group-by version. I am trying to understand why this happens, because as far as I understand, 'group by' syntax is used after aggregation, BUT why here it doesn't work?**

**The where clause version - correct:**

```
SELECT 
    c.client_id,
    c.name,
    (SELECT AVG(invoice_total) FROM invoices) AS average,
    (SELECT sum(invoice_total) FROM invoices where client_id=c.client_id) AS total_sales,
    (SELECT average - total_sales) AS differences
FROM clients c;
```

**The group-by version - wrong**

```
SELECT 
    c.client_id,
    c.name,
    (SELECT AVG(invoice_total) FROM invoices) AS average,
    (SELECT sum(invoice_total) FROM invoices GROUP BY client_id) AS total_sales,
    (SELECT average - total_sales) AS differences
FROM clients c;
```

Thank you for all the answers in advance!

I am trying to understand the logic why "group by" syntax does not apply here.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help your question.

Comment: What `Mysql doesn't execute the group-by version` means? Do you get an error? Don´t get the expected results? The `where`and the `group by`are different instructions, so your queries are  going to get different results

Comment: And, no, the "where clause version" is not correct. It is invalid, because you cannot define an alias in a select clause and use that alias in the same select clause. The DBMS doesn't have to do your selects top down. It could decide to evaluate "differences" first, but for this to happen, "average" and "total_sales" would have to be known already.

Comment: Without sample data and expected outcome it is pure guessing what query would be best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be getting the error, "Subquery returns more than one row".
now, if we see your group by subquery:
select sum(invoice_total) from invoice group by client_id;
this particular query will give a relation in result with sum of invoice_total of each client.

now if you are using this query as a subquery, you should corelate it to the outer query.

select c.client_id, c.client_name, (select sum(invoice_total) from invoice) as total_sales from client c;

here result you will be expecting is
client's id | client's name | total_sales

but you won't get it because the inner sub query is resulting in a whole relation, it is not relating with the outer query's id and name.
you expect total_sales value corresponding to the outer query's client_id so, we have to use "where" clause joining c.client_id=client_id which is not happening with "group by" query.

I hope you get it. Sorry if you don't, i tried my best explaining.

Comment: Thank you for your explicit response!! Now I understand the reason why it won't work the other way around.